# Spring Cloud Gateway, how to programatically get the matched route information

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

For a sample route definition below, when the control goes to `MyCustomFilter`, Is there any way to get the following information

1. log the route id that is matched (in this case it is "test-route")
2. log absolute value of the URI of this route definition that is matched (http://my-downstream-service.com)

Route Definition:

```
  - id: test-route
    uri: http://my-downstream-service.com
    predicates:
      - Path=/v3/status
      - Method=POST
    filters:
      - MyCustomFilter
```

Answer (score 2):

All the matched route information like id, URI, predicates & filters are available in `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route`, all we need to do is to get the handle of the Route object using the below statement in any of the filters.

```
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route route = exchange.getAttribute(org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
```

and get the required information like `route.getId()`